# How to prevent event bubbling on child of React-Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) map which I am rendering a `div` inside.

For some reason, interacting with the contents of the div causes the map beneath to respond (eg: double-clicking will zoom the map, dragging will pan the map) - even when I'm calling `e.stopPropagation()` in handlers attached to the div.

As I understand it, calling `stopPropagation()` should prevent the DOM events from ever reaching the map itself.

Why does it appear that `stopPropagation()` is being ignored?

How can I render a div *inside the map* without it's events bubbling to the map itself?

[Here is an example codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjJdvw?editors=0110) showing the problem.

```
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

const MyMap = props => (
  <Map zoom={13} center={[51.505, -0.09]}>
    <TileLayer url={"http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"} />

    {/* 
          HOW do I get this div to NOT pass it's events down to the map?!?! 
          Why does e.stopPropagation() appear to not work?
    */}
    <div 
      id="zone"
      onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
      onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
      onMouseUp={e => e.stopPropagation()}
    >
      <p>Double-click or click and drag inside this square</p>
      <p>Why does the map zoom/pan?</p>
    </div>

  </Map>
);

ReactDOM.render(<MyMap />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Leaflet map use [`L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#domevent-disableclickpropagation) instead which:

> Adds `stopPropagation` to the element's `'click'`, `'doubleclick'`,
>   `'mousedown'` and `'touchstart'` events.

Example

```
function MyMap() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Map zoom={13} center={[51.505, -0.09]}>
        <TileLayer url={"http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"} />
        <MyInfo />
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}
```

where

```
function MyInfo() {
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(divRef.current);
  });

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} id="zone">
      <p>Double-click or click and drag inside this square</p>
      <p>Why does the map zoom/pan?</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/qzwMaa?editors=0110)

**Alternative option**

Another option to stop div element from propagation to map events would be to place div *outside* of the map element:

```
<div>
  <Map zoom={13} center={[51.505, -0.09]}>
    <TileLayer url={"http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"} />
  </Map>
  <MyInfo />
</div>
```

where

```
function MyInfo() {
  return (
    <div id="zone">
      <p>Double-click or click and drag inside this square</p>
      <p>Why does the map zoom/pan?</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would love to know why `e.stopPropagation()` on the div itself doesn't work tho.  How does Leaflet receive these events if they're not passed up from the div?

Comment: The way how Leaflet register event listeners [internally](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/3084db0bcb92c8bc5e8f68d297ee8feabed5de98/src/dom/DomEvent.js#L188),some extra steps are performed to register `click` event handler for Leaflet controls (such as `ZoomIn` control).  Registering `stopPropagation` for div element _only_ does not prevent leaflet controls  click event to fire (that's the reason why map gets zoom in/out)

Comment: Error message occurs `L is not defined`

Comment: @Tekson `import L from 'leaflet';`

Comment: I tried this approach. It works, but now the problem is I can't click on the select box(mui select) inside a div inside map.

Comment: The ref might be null inside the `useEffect` (therefore throwing errors like `Cannot read properties of null (reading '_leaflet_events')`). It's better to handle it while it's being assigned, like `ref={(ref) => {if (!ref) return; L.DomEvents.disableClickPropagation(ref); }}`. I've answered the question with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those using more recent versions of `react-leaflet` (e.g.: `^4.2.1`), I could only make it work with [react-leaflet-custom-control](https://github.com/chris-m92/react-leaflet-custom-control)

```
{/* import Control from "react-leaflet-custom-control"; */}
<Control position="topright">
  <div
    ref={(ref) => {
      if (!ref) return;
      /** import L from "leaflet"; */
      L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(ref).disableScrollPropagation(ref);
    }}
  >
    <button onClick={() => console.log('Clicked')}>Click me</button>
  </div>
</Control>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-custom-control-event-issue-rz2ri1?file=/src/App.js:83-107)